SMW Property:Links to, Where do I find it?
Apologies if this has already been answered, However I was trying to implement a module, however had the “[Links to :: ]” syntax in a query. I’m not familiar with this, nor do I recognise this from SMW. I’ve done quite a bit of googling however I have yet to stumble upon an extension that implements this.
I searched around in the ExtraSpecialProperties extension, however couldn’t find it, I also found this question using it, however no context was given: Semantic MediaWiki Get page links?

You will need the extension Semantic Scribunto.
Having installed that, you can call mw.smw.getQueryResult() or mw.smw.ask().
Both functions, especially the latter, return rather complex Lua tables; you could use mw.dumpObject() or mw.logObject() to study the structure of the returned tables in the console below the module edit window, in order to find out how to extract only the data you need.

Just to clarify, does Semantic Scribunto define Property:Links to? Currently it hasn’t yet been installed due to some issues (although will be soon). I thought I’d look through some of the modules first to find anything else that needed to be installed before then.

No, you ought to create Property:Links to yourself; and then include [[Links to:...]] or {{#set:Links to=...}} into any template you want. No MediaWiki extension creates a special property for any wikilink; and it is not likely than any will.
